# Load WKT polygons from MVC for OpenLayers to render

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openlayers-3

OL3 and MVC5. I have an mvc controller that returns wkt polygon strings from oracle. I want to render these in open layers but i can't find out what the format should look like to make ol happy.

```
   var tAVectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.WKT(),
    url: function (extent) {
        return '/MyController/Map/MyWKTPolygons';
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
});

var tAVectors = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: tAreaVectorSource,
    style: tAStyle
});
```

my controller is returning this:

```
{"TAId":4,"PId":21,"TType":1,"TShape":"POLYGON ((-1.2695884640625E7 4445506.375, -1.21430920625E7 4451637.25, -1.2152876E7 5012485.703125, -1.2373014640625E7 5006005.84375, -1.2373014640625E7 5162735.015625, -1.2695884640625E7 5156153.28125, -1.2695884640625E7 4445506.375))","TAcres":0}
```

Right now i get

> Unexpected character: {

before that i was testing returning several features and the Unexpected character was the [ brace defining the list.
What would OL like and where can i find the spec or an example to make it satisfied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller is returning JSON which contains a WKT string as attribute. When using `ol.format.WKT` your controller should only return the WKT string (`POLYGON (...)`).

You might want to use GeoJSON if you are also interested in getting the properties of your features.

Comment: I will need attributes.  Can mvc create geoJson?

Comment: I don't know ASP MVC, but there might be libraries that generate GeoJSON. Oracle might also be able to generate GeoJSON.

Comment: also, what if i want to return more than one wkt feature?